# How to make a JNI for a Java Interface?

Tags: java, c++, interface, java-native-interface

How can I make a JNI for a Java Interface so that I can call a function from the interface in c++ code?

Specifically, I have a Java interface

```
public interface Foo {
    public void Bar(int a);
}
```

which I attempted to create a JNI for
*JFoo.h:*

```
class JFoo {
    ...
    public: 
        void Bar(int a);
    ...
};
```

*JFoo.c:*

```
...
void JFoo::Bar(int a) {
    //Not sure what to put here. If I don't have then I have issues because 
    "declaration of 'void JFoo::Bar(int)' outside of class is not 
    definition"
    return;
} 
...
```

So from another C++ file I can do

```
JFoo foo123;
foo123 = ... //the Java object which implements the Foo interface is what actually passes in 'foo123'
foo123.bar(5); //This ideally executes the Java object's implementation of bar
```

I also tried to use `virtual void` in JFoo instead to have an abstract c++ class, but that doesn't work because you "cannot declare field 'foo123' to be of abstract type".

How can I make the JNI for the Java interface?

Comment: To declare a JNI method, Java has a special `native` keyword.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation? Instead of just guessing?

Comment: I'm aware of the `native` keyword and am using that (just didn't include full code in my question), thanks! 

Could you help point me to the right documentation?  I've done a lot of searching, but it's rather difficult to narrow down specifically to creating a JNI of a Java Interface given JNI stands for Java Native Interface.  :( I successfully created a JNI of a Java Class, but you're right I am just guessing for an Interface as opposed to a Class.

Comment: Check the [jni tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jni/info).

Comment: You should start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/index.html), then read the tool documentation for `javah` and the JNI Specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it doesn't work like that :(

You can't go like this. JNI allows you to call native methods and manipulate Java objects via functions provided in JNI implementation. But it has nothing to do with one to one mapping.

Take a look here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo025

This sample shows how to call method of class from C++.

Comment: .oOo. I love the smell of the downvote (without explanation) in the morning ;) .oOo.

Answer (score 1):

JNI is for implementing instance (without `static`) or class (`static`) methods. A method implementation implies a concrete method even if the class contains other methods that are abstract. An interface's methods are entirely abstract.

The language documentation indicates that `native` is a permissible modifier for a method in a [class declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3) but does not for an [interface declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4). The compiler will also tell you where you can't put `native`.